# Add custom links to www-interface of dask distributed scheduler

Tags: python, distributed, dask

When the scheduler of the dask distributed runs, it show web-gui available by default on port 8787.

Currently it contains links to pages, displaying status of workers, tasks, CPU and network load, etc

How can I add something custom to this page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That page is a [Bokeh server application](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html)

The code lives here: https://github.com/dask/distributed/tree/master/distributed/bokeh

If you only want to add a link then you can modify the template found here: https://github.com/dask/distributed/blob/master/distributed/bokeh/status/templates/index.html